# SARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,1)7 Math Formula

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

Would the correct mathematical way to write a SARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,1)7 Model be:

$$
(1-\Phi_1B)(1-B)(1-B^7)y_t= (1+\Theta_1B)(1+\Theta_1B^7)\varepsilon_t
$$

I am new to the ARIMA world and I am trying to understand as best I can writing the model in mathematical terms.

This source was used as guidance link:
https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html.

**Where**:

$(1-\Phi_1B) $ -> is the non-seasonal AR(1) component

$(1-B) $ -> Is the Non seasonal Difference

$(1-B^7)$ -> is the seasonal difference

**And...**

$(1+\Theta_1B)$ -> nonseasonal MA

$(1+\Theta_1B^7)$ -> is the Seasonal MA(1) component

Comment: See [these treads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+model+equation). Yours is most likely a duplicate of at least one of them.

Comment: I suppose there are $\theta_1$ and $\Theta_1$, not $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_1$.